# Computing the expected value of $f$ where $\mu$ is a function of $f$

Tags: probability-theory

I am curious about the following scenario (This may not be the most sensible set up because I am puzzling this out independent of any homework etc).

Suppose $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ then it is pretty standard to find the expectation of $f(X)$ by computing

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\int_{\Omega} f(x)N(x;\mu,\sigma)dx.$$

Now, I would like to treat $f$ as the composition of two different operators $f(X) = g\circ h(X)$ where $h$ shifts $\mu$ to a new value $\mu_{*}$ in a smooth  or otherwise "nice" manner and $g$ is something simple and uninteresting like $g(x) = x^{2}+1.$ That is, $g$ is something you might see in a textbook when you learn how to compute the expectation of a function of a random variable for the first time.

My question then is simply is, does everything still makes sense? Or did I break something by attempting this construction?

Incase this question was confusing, to attempt to put it in plain words:

When I compute

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\int_{\Omega} f(x)N(x;\mu,\sigma)dx.$$

I would like to take it so that for each $x\in \Omega$, $f$ first changes $\mu$ and then proceeds to compute the integral as usual.

As for my effort:

In the easiest case I came up with  where $X$ is standard normal, where $h(x)$ shifts $\mu$ to $x$ and $g(x) = 1$, I think I would get

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X)) = \int_{\Omega}f(x)N(x;0,1)dx = \int_{\Omega}h(x)N(x;0,1)dx = \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx.$$

Then if I blindly take $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and use the Cauchy Principal Value just because it seems like a reasonable thing to do, I get

$$\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx = \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-a}^{a}dx = \infty$$

but evaluating to $\infty$ seems both reasonable and looks like I did something very incorrect at the same time.

I am not necessarily interested solely in changing $\mu$ or the normal distribution, but trying to write up my question generalizing it to other possible distributions or parameters was getting over my head.

Comment: What do you mean by "shifts $\mu$ to $x$"?  It seems you are trying to magic away the exponent $\mathsf e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$ by ... doing ... what?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Basically, in a big picture idea because I don't know how to properly write down what I want: When $h$ is applied to the Gaussian, as the integral ranges over the $x$, I want $h$ to first apply to the Gaussian and change $\mu$. So that for each $x$ that the integral ranges over, $h(x)$ applies to the Gaussian and changes $\mu$ to whatever the value $x$ happens to be to get $e^{-(x-x)^2/2\sigma^{2}} = e^{0} = 1$ over all of $\Omega$ .

Comment: I suppose a better way to describe it is that the action of $h$ takes the normally constant parameter $\mu$ and redefines it to into a function $\mu(x) := x$.

Comment: That's not going to work.  You're trying to change the distribution's probability density function into something that is *not* a probability density function ... somehow ... and wondering why the resulting expectation doesn't exist.

Comment: I am still unconvinced because I could have calculated $\mathbb{E}(e^{X^{2}}/2)$  where $X$ follows a standard normal and I would have ended up at a similar step.

Comment: The expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists if $\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \int_{\Omega} |X| \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}<\infty$ similarly $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ exists if $\int_{\Omega} |f(X)| \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} < \infty$. It is important to remember about integrability conditions. Is this what you wanted, because I'm not sure if I followed.